Can vite resolve path alias in plugins?
vite.config.ts
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import { defineConfig, type ViteDevServer } from 'vite';

const xServer = {
    name: 'xServer',
    async configureServer(server: ViteDevServer) {              
        const { doX } = await import('./src/lib/x');
        doX(server)
    }
}

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [xServer, sveltekit()],
});

x.ts
import { doY } from "$lib/y";
import type { ViteDevServer } from "vite";

export async function doX(devServer: ViteDevServer) {
   doY()
   ...
}

Error:

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package '$lib' imported from
...vite.config.ts

You may suggest add to the config:
resolve: {
   alias: {
      '$lib': path.join(__dirname, 'src/lib'),
    },
}

But it does not affect the plugin(by default controlled via sveltekit).
I also read this, which is about this problem, but it doesn't work and the article contains errors in the code.
Well, I've spent enough time to wonder if this is even possible?

I don't think this is possible unless you essentially build the config first, resolving the paths in the process, and use the output in Vite.

I just decided to import from build instead of src - it's not pretty, but  works...  On the other hand, I think it's expected that plugins are a separate package, I just have unusual code.

You can always just use relative paths instead, no need to use $lib. From the root it does not even contain many ../../.., it's just './src/lib/y'. (Though this probably does not work for TS files .)

Yes, it is possible to use relative paths. But the project is much bigger than the example. And auto-import imports with $lib, so I had to change them to relative paths manually, which is slow and inconvenient.
